# how to detect when a user clicks on an option in a drop down menu (select tag)

Tags: javascript, html, select

I have a select and I want to run a different javascript function depending on what they select when they click it in the menu.  My googling has been unfruitful, can anyone direct me to the correct property? (for example, I know that onclick works well with buttons).  Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT: onchange doesn't work in my code.

```
<head>
    <script>
        function goToDelete(){
            document.write("Death to this webpage!")
        }
    </script>
</head>
<form id="checkboxes" method="post" action="someurl">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="Selection"/></td>
        <td>Some more rows to the table here</td>
    </tr>
    <select name="action">
        <option value="Delete" onchange="goToDelete()">Delete</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/change

Comment: if you plan on taking an answer using a library (`jQuery`), don't forget the [**performance issue**](http://jsperf.com/jquery-change-vs-change)

Answer (score 8):

I'd suggest using the `change`/`onchange` event, though this only fires if the user selects an `option` that wasn't previously selected (hence the name).

A simple demonstration of how you can use `change` (tested in Chrome 27/Windows XP):

```
var select = document.getElementById('demo');

function logValue() {
    switch (this.value) {
        case '1':
            console.log('option 1 selected');
            break;
        case '2':
            alert('option 2 selected');
            break;
        case '3':
            confirm('You chose option 3, didn\'t you?');
            break;
    }
}

select.addEventListener('change', logValue, false);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rCsDB/).

It's important to note that the `change`/`onchange` event must be bound to the `select` element, [*not* the `option` elements](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rCsDB/1/). The `option`s themselves don't change, selecting them *triggers* the change.

References:

- [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/change).

Answer (score 5):

```
function SelectedValue(sel) {
    var value = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;  
    //Do something depending on value
}
<select id="myid" onchange="SelectedValue(this)">
    <option value="">Select options</option>
    <option value="Value1">Text1</option>
    <option value="Value2">Text2</option>
    <option value="Value3">Text3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use jQuery on and off, like this:

```
$('body').on('change', '#yourSelectId', function(){
      // do what you need
});
```

Comment: If you're going to suggest using a library to handle native events (and not necessarily a bad idea), please take the time to explain why. What's the benefit of jQuery in this scenario?

Answer (score -1):

`change function()` from [jQuery](http://jquery.comn) will help you to do that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#yourselectInput").change(function(){

alert("item had change!!");

})
})
```

Live example

http://jsbin.com/unujiz/1/edit